# IOWebSocketChannel detect when the connection is open

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to dart/flutter. I'm trying to use [WebSocketChannel](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel) to connect to a websocket server.

Is there a way to detect when the connection with server is completed?

What I want to do is to send some messages the moment the connection with server is completed.

In javascript implementation this was something done like this:

```
exampleSocket.onopen = function (event) {
  exampleSocket.send("Here's some text that the server is urgently awaiting!"); 
};
```

Is there an alternative on dart/flutter ? Is it possible to use it with `WebSocketChannel`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [WebSocket](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-io/WebSocket-class.html)
class static method [connect](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-io/WebSocket/connect.html) 
returns a Future that resolve to a web socket when the connection is established.

If you want to send a message when the connection is up something like that should work:

```
  import 'dart:io';
  import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

  WebSocket.connect("ws://a.b.c.d").then((ws) {

    // create the stream channel 
    var channel = IOWebSocketChannel(ws);

    channel.sink.add("hello");
  })
```

The package [web_socket_channel](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel) must be added to `pubspec.yaml` dependencies.

Comment: Thanks man! Was searching for a solution and this filled it perfectly

Answer (score 2):

In latest version of [WebSocketChannel 2.4.0](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel) there is [`ready`](https://pub.dev/documentation/web_socket_channel/latest/web_socket_channel/WebSocketChannel/ready.html) Future.

```dart
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://localhost:3000',
      connectTimeout: Duration(seconds: 20),
      pingInterval: Duration(seconds: 15));

channel.stream.listen((event) {
  print('got message');
});

await channel.ready; // ready is a future

print('WS connected');

channel.sink.add('hi'); // write data to websocket
```